# Can't develop with HTTP, always getting redirected to HTTPS

Tags: c#, https, asp.net-core-mvc

I was testing my ASP.NET CORE MVC webapp with HTTPS configuration. To do so, i put on startup.ConfiguraServices:

```
services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
        {
            options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
            options.HttpsPort = 443;
        });
```

On startup.Configure:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

and configured the Kestrel server as follows:

```
public static void ConfigureKestrelServerOptions(this KestrelServerOptions options)
    {
        var configurationService = options.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        var environmentService = options.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();

        var endpoints = configurationService.GetSection("HttpServer:Endpoints")
            .GetChildren()
            .ToDictionary(section => section.Key, section =>
            {
                var endpoint = new EndPointSettings();
                section.Bind(endpoint);
                return endpoint;
            });

        foreach (var endpoint in endpoints)
        {
            var config = endpoint.Value;
            var port = config.Port ?? (config.Scheme == "https" ? 443 : 8080);

            var ipAddresses = new List<IPAddress>();
            if (config.Host == "localhost")
            {
                ipAddresses.Add(IPAddress.IPv6Loopback);
                ipAddresses.Add(IPAddress.Loopback);
            }
            else if (IPAddress.TryParse(config.Host, out var address))
            {
                ipAddresses.Add(address);
            }
            else
            {
                ipAddresses.Add(IPAddress.IPv6Any);
            }

            foreach (var address in ipAddresses)
            {
                options.Listen(address, port,
                    listenOptions =>
                    {
                        if (config.Scheme == "https")
                        {
                            var certificate = LoadCertificate(config, environmentService);
                            listenOptions.UseHttps(certificate);
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    }

WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseKestrel(options => options.ConfigureKestrelServerOptions())
```

After that, i added an X509 certificate on Chrome and all https was working fine.

The problem is that now, i want to debug back with http protocol, and for that i supposed that commenting all the lines above should be sufficent, but each time i try to go to URL *"**http**://localhost:8080"* it redirects to *"**https**://localhost/Account/LogIn?ReturnUrl=%2F"*.

I've tried to delete Chrome's HSTS for localhost and localhost:8080; an i've tried to execute the server in a different port with no luck.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: You have to work in a mode that is compatible with the server.  The server only is running as a Secure Server.  When a connection is made between a client and server there is a negotiation that occurs using the headers in the request to find a common mode of operation.  For example a server may support different languages like English, French, German.  A client will specify the language is English an then the server will connect to a Web-page that is in English.

Comment: Sorry, but could you explain it further? Why is the server running only as Secure Server? I thought the configuration above is valid for HTTP and HTTPS... In any case, i've also tried to launch Kestrel without any configuration, just with its default values.

Comment: Do you disable the redirect for development mode?

Comment: Port 443 is a secure port number for email.  Use port 25 for non secure email.

Comment: I had this same issue. On Firefox I deleted the cache / cookies relating to my development site and that solved it.

Comment: Have you configured `[Authorize]` in your endpoint? For redirect to Login, I am afraid it is not related with `UseHttpsRedirection`. Do you mean you expect `http://localhost/Account/LogIn?ReturnUrl=%2F` when request `http://localhost:8080`?

Answer (score 0):

Within this configuration you are forcing to all HTTP request to be redirected on HTTPS. If you want to be able to use both configurations, it should be enough to use this configuration (and at development method it could be sufficent):

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000); 
                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, listenOptions => { listenOptions.UseHttps(); });
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

If I run this configuration, I am clearly able to access the both endpoints.

Address `http://localhost:5000` is able to listen all HTTP request.
 Address `https://localhost:5001` is able to listen all HTTPS requests.

However, it needs to run `Kestrel` without reversed proxy `IIS`, because it overrides set endpoints in the current configuration. If you run program within Visual Studio, properties of WebApplication in debug mode should be set on *Profile* name of your webapplication and *Launch* should be type of `Project`.

The problem why you are not able run HTTP even with commented lines above, could be the fact, that HSTS is highly cachable *(according to microsoft docs)*. I would suspect the browser, that somewhere in cache are saved some informations, about how does the communication between client and server should work. So it could causes the redirection, even the configuration is set off.